# Reading BMP RGBA using python PIL doesn't work

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read a RGBA BMP using python PIL, and it doesn't seem to work.
The following code segment shows that tensorflow bmp_decode function succeeds in this task, while PIL doesn't:

```
def read_image_tf(filename):
    image_file = tf.read_file(filename, name='read_file')                    
    decoded_bmp = tf.io.decode_bmp(bmp_image)
    return decoded_bmp
def read_img_pil(filename):
    img = np.asarray(Image.open(fh))
    return img

img = K.eval(read_image_tf(<FILENAME>))
print (img.shape)
img = read_img_pil(<FILENAME>)
print (img.shape)
```

Output:

```
(3892, 3892, 4)
(3892, 3892, 3)
```

When trying to run `imgobj.convert('RGBA')` on `Image.open(fh)` I simply get a matrix that contains only the value of 255 (100% transparency, which is not the correct alpha value per pixel).

Is there a bug in PIL? Is there an alternative to reading RGBA using python?

Comment: Can you share the troublesome BMP file please? You may have to use Dropbox or Google Drive or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PIL** doesn't support 32 bit bitmap images. As the [official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#bmp) states:-

> Pillow reads and writes Windows and OS/2 BMP files containing `1`, `L`, `P`, or `RGB` data. 16-colour images are read as P images. Run-length encoding is not supported.

That's why it is generally recommended not to use `Image.show()` to view an image, as it converts the image to `.bmp` before displaying it. Therefore if the image contained alpha values (image of color mode `LA`, `RGBA` etc) the displayed image will not be display properly, and will have artifacts.

Therefore, when you try to open a `.bmp` image having `RGBA` color space in PIL, the color space gets truncated to `RGB`.

**Example:-**

```
from PIL import Image

# creating an red colored image with RGBA color space and full opacity
img = Image.new("RGBA", (100, 100), (255, 0, 0, 255))

# displaying the color mode of the image
print(img.mode)

# saving the image as a .bmp (bitmap)
img.save("new.bmp")

# Opening the previously saved .bmp image (having color mode RGBA)
img = Image.open("new.bmp")

# displaying the mode of the .bmp file
print(img.mode)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
RGBA
RGB
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. So how would you suggest reading a RGBA bmp file using python?

Comment: @Protostome You can use `cv2` (OpenCV) library for that. `cv2` is far more robust when it comes to image processing then PIL.

Comment: That works, thanks. For any future visitors - this is how I read a RGBA BMP with cv2: `cv2.imread(FILENAME,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`